# How to prevent using a parameter when before clicked in Livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

This code is a part of the View file connected with the Livewire component.

How to prevent using a parameter when before a button clicked?

**View**

```
    ...
        @foreach ($babies as $baby)
    ...
                <div
                    class="flex justify-between w-11-12 py-1  mb-1 ml-2 leading-6 text-sm font-medium ext-left text-white uppercase transition rounded shadow ripple hover:shadow-lg hover:bg-blue-800 focus:outline-none">
                    <button wire:click="setAte({{ $baby, $ate = 0 }})"
                        class="flex w-1-3 mr-1 px-2 text-xs font-medium text-center text-white uppercase transition rounded shadow ripple hover:shadow-lg hover:bg-pink-800 focus:ring-ring-600 {{ $baby['ate'] == 0 ? "bg-blue-500" : "bg-red-500"   }}">
                        S</button>
                    <button wire:click="setAte({{ $baby, $ate = 1 }})"
                        class="flex w-1-3 mr-1 px-2 text-xs font-medium text-center text-white uppercase transition rounded shadow ripple hover:shadow-lg hover:bg-pink-800 focus:ring-pink-600 {{ $baby['ate'] == 1 ? "bg-blue-500" : "bg-red-500"}}">
                        M</button>
                    <button wire:click="setAte({{ $baby, $ate = 2}})"
                        class="flex w-1-3 px-2 text-xs font-medium text-center text-white uppercase transition rounded shadow ripple hover:shadow-lg hover:bg-pink-800 focus:ring-pink-600 {{ $baby['ate'] == 2 ? "bg-blue-500" : "bg-red-500"  }}">
                        L</button>
                    <div>{{ $baby['ate'] }}</div> {{-- <---check code --}}
                </div>
    @endforeach
    ...
```

**Component**

```
public function setAte($baby, $ate)
{
    $baby['ate'] = $ate;
    $selectedBaby = Baby::find($baby['id']);
    $selectedBaby->save();
}
```

**Error**

> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
> Unable to resolve dependency [Parameter #1 [  $ate ]] in class App\Http\Livewire\Classroom\BabyStatus

[image]

**Solution 1**

//Component

```
public $baby;

protected $rules = [
    'baby.ate' => 'required|int|min:0|max:2'
];

public function updateAte($ate)
{
    $this->baby->ate = $ate;
    $this->baby->save();
}
```

//View

```
<button wire:model="baby" wire:click="updateAte(0)"
    class="flex w-1-3 mr-1 px-2 text-xs font-medium text-center text-white uppercase transition rounded shadow ripple hover:shadow-lg hover:bg-pink-800 focus:ring-ring-600 {{ $baby['ate'] == 0 ? "bg-blue-500" : "bg-red-500"}}">S</button>
<button wire:model="baby" wire:click="updateAte(1)"
    class="flex w-1-3 mr-1 px-2 text-xs font-medium text-center text-white uppercase transition rounded shadow ripple hover:shadow-lg hover:bg-pink-800 focus:ring-pink-600 {{ $baby['ate'] == 1 ? "bg-blue-500" : "bg-red-500"}}">M</button>
<button wire:model="baby" wire:click="updateAte(2)"
    class="flex w-1-3 px-2 text-xs font-medium text-center text-white uppercase transition rounded shadow ripple hover:shadow-lg hover:bg-pink-800 focus:ring-pink-600 {{ $baby['ate'] == 2 ? "bg-blue-500" : "bg-red-500"  }}">L</button>
```

That's all, thank you @Unflux.

Answer (score 1):

I would be inclined to refactor what you have and make each `baby` a separate `livewire component`.

**App\Http\Livewire\Baby.php**

```
class Baby extends Component
{
    // your instance of a baby
    public $baby;

    // required to allow updating of the baby properties
    protected $rules = [
        'baby.ate' => 'required|int|min:0|max:2'
    ];

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.baby');
    }

    // you can set the value of properties here if you want
    public function mount()
    {
        // for example:
        //$this->baby->ate = -100;
    }

    // when the value of ate is updated from the view
    // update the baby model
    public function updatedBaby()
    {
        $this->baby->save();
    }
}
```

**resoures\views\livewire\baby.blade.php**

```
<div class="p-4 m-4">
    <h4>Baby Component - ate: {{ $baby->ate }}</h4>
    <div class="flex justify-between p-4 m-4">
        <button wire:click="$set('baby.ate', 0)"
                class="text-white px-2 rounded {{ $baby->ate === 0 ? "bg-blue-500" : "bg-red-500" }}">S
        </button>
        <button wire:click="$set('baby.ate', 1)"
                class="text-white px-2 rounded {{ $baby->ate === 1 ? "bg-blue-500" : "bg-red-500" }}">M
        </button>
        <button wire:click="$set('baby.ate', 2)"
                class="text-white px-2 rounded {{ $baby->ate === 2 ? "bg-blue-500" : "bg-red-500" }}">L
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** The use of `===` in the above. Prevents `null` or similar values being incorrectly determined as equal to `0`.

Then in your `view`:

```
@foreach($babies as $baby)
  @livewire("baby", ["baby" => $baby]) // render your single baby component
@endforeach
```

Comment: thanks, but it couldn't rerender with updated ```$baby['ate' ] ``` in the child component.

Comment: @JsWizard What is `$baby`, is it an array or a model?

Comment: Now it also working in child component, but new problem occurred that rerendering issue. I think updated ```$baby``` data must pass to parents component, right?

Comment: If you are using the updated `$baby` model in your parent component then yes, you will need to inform the parent. If you're parent is just looping over the `$babies` collection and not doing anything else, I would remove it and just use a normal blade `@foreach` as in my example.

Comment: I solved it with using ```return redirect()->to('/child-component');``` in the end of there update method, but it's now elegant way.

Comment: Is there any way to rerender only this child component??

Comment: If you have followed my example accurately, only the effected `baby` component will update. I am a confused what you're trying to do. Maybe update your question?

Comment: -_- your advice didn't work to update DB, it seems just update in frontend side. How to solve with ```wire:click=``` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226618/discussion-between-unflux-and-jswizard).